# parse xml with many childs (XmlRpc Response)

Tags: apex, xml

This is the monster I receive after a GET request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
<params>
    <param>
        <value>
            <array>
                <data>
                    <value>
                        <struct>
                            <member>
                                <name>DateCreated</name>
                                <value><dateTime.iso8601>20160830T12:57:13</dateTime.iso8601></value>
                            </member>
                            <member>
                                <name>Id</name>
                                <value><i4>17</i4></value>
                            </member>
                        </struct>
                    </value>
                    <value>
                        <struct>
                            <member>
                                <name>DateCreated</name>
                                <value><dateTime.iso8601>20160830T15:57:25</dateTime.iso8601></value>
                            </member>
                            <member>
                                <name>Id</name>
                                <value><i4>43</i4></value>
                            </member>
                        </struct>
                    </value>
                </data>
            </array>
        </value>
    </param>
</params>
</methodResponse>
```

I want to get the DateCreated and Id values.

The server may send multiple Ids with different created dates. Is it possible to compare the DateCreated values to get the most recent value?

Here is what I've been able to come with after looking at the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm)

```
Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();

Dom.XmlNode methodResponse = doc.getRootElement();

String dateCreated = methodResponse.getChildElement('params', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('array', null)
                    .getChildElement('data', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('struct', null)
                    .getChildElement('member', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null).getText();

String theId = methodResponse.getChildElement('params', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('array', null)
                    .getChildElement('data', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('struct', null)
                    .getChildElement('member', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null).getText();
return theId;
```

The return value from theId is

> Text Node
>   Value   [154]|methodResponse|"XMLNode[ELEMENT,methodResponse,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,params,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,param,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,value,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,array,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,data,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,value,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,struct,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,member,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,name,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,DateCreated,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,value,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,dateTime.iso8601,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,20160830T12:57:13,]],null,]],null,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,member,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,name,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,Id,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,value,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,i4,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,17,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,value,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,struct,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,member,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,name,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,DateCreated,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,value,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,dateTime.iso8601,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,20160830T15:57:25,]],null,]],null,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,member,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,name,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,Id,]],null,], XMLNode[ELEMENT,value,null,null,null,[XMLNode[ELEMENT,i4,null,null,null,[XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,43,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]],null,]"|0x7d6901eb

Comment: Take a look at [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm). You should be able to figure out how to parse a `List<Datetime>` and just sort it.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I'm going to add an XmlRpc class to my upcoming library now.

Comment: @AdrianLarson [eXtensible Markup Language-Remote Procedure Call](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html). It's a standard protocol for calling a method on a server, like SOAP, but more bloated.

Comment: @AdrianLarson if you could look at my updated post after looking at the link you shared I'd appreciate it! :D

Comment: I applaud your use of chaining, but to debug this error you may want to abandon it temporarily. Try breaking out each node separately and debugging them to see which one is null. I'm guessing the `.` in the `dateTime.iso8601` is giving you problems, but I haven't the time to check.

Comment: @AdrianLarson that was the issue,  my post is updated, but now it's returning another monster..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below function will return the most recent `Id` from your `HttpResponse`.

```
public Id getLatestId(HttpResponse res){
    Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
    Dom.XmlNode methodResponse = doc.getRootElement();

    List<Dom.XmlNode> dataNodes = methodResponse.getChildElement('params', null)
                    .getChildElement('param', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('array', null)
                    .getChildElement('data', null)
                    .getChildElements();

    List<DateTime> datesToSort = new List<DateTime>();
    Map<DateTime, String> dateToIdMap = new Map<DateTime, String>();

    for(Dom.XmlNode dNode : dataNodes){
        List<Dom.XmlNode> memberNodes = dNode.getChildElement('struct', null)
                    .getChildElements();

        DateTime createdDate = null;
        String id = '';

        for(Dom.XmlNode mNode : memberNodes){
            String name = mNode.getChildElement('name', null)
                    .getText();

            if(name == 'DateCreated'){
                String dt  = mNode.getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('dateTime.iso8601', null)
                    .getText();
                //need to prepare the DateTime string for JSON parsing
                dt = dt.substring(0, 4) + '-' + dt.substring(4,6) + '-' + dt.substring(6, dt.length());
                createdDate = (DateTime) JSON.deserialize('"'+dt+'"', DateTime.class);
            }else if(name == 'Id'){
                id  = mNode.getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('i4', null)
                    .getText();
            }     
        }

        datesToSort.add(createdDate);
        dateToIdMap.put(createdDate, id);  
    }

    datesToSort.sort();
    String latestId = dateToIdMap.get(datesToSort.get(datesToSort.size()-1));
    System.debug(latestId);
    return latestId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
'<methodResponse>'+
'<params>'+
'    <param>'+
'        <value>'+
'            <array>'+
'                <data>'+
'                    <value>'+
'                        <struct>'+
'                            <member>'+
'                                <name>DateCreated</name>'+
'                                <value><dateTime.iso8601>20160830T12:57:13</dateTime.iso8601></value>'+
'                            </member>'+
'                            <member>'+
'                                <name>Id</name>'+
'                                <value><i4>17</i4></value>'+
'                            </member>'+
'                        </struct>'+
'                    </value>'+
'                    <value>'+
'                        <struct>'+
'                            <member>'+
'                                <name>DateCreated</name>'+
'                                <value><dateTime.iso8601>20160830T15:57:25</dateTime.iso8601></value>'+
'                            </member>'+
'                            <member>'+
'                                <name>Id</name>'+
'                                <value><i4>43</i4></value>'+
'                            </member>'+
'                        </struct>'+
'                    </value>'+
'                </data>'+
'            </array>'+
'        </value>'+
'    </param>'+
'</params>'+
'</methodResponse>';


Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(s);
Dom.XmlNode methodResponse = doc.getRootElement();

String dateCreated = methodResponse.getChildElement('params', null)
                    .getChildElement('param', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('array', null)
                    .getChildElement('data', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('struct', null)
                    .getChildElement('member', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('dateTime.iso8601', null)
                    .getText();
System.debug('>>' + dateCreated);

String theId = methodResponse.getChildElement('params', null)
                    .getChildElement('param', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('array', null)
                    .getChildElement('data', null)
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('struct', null)
                    .getChildElements()[1]
                    .getChildElement('value', null)
                    .getChildElement('i4', null).getText();

System.debug('>>' + theId );
```

Once you get the ID and date then you can easily find most recent value.

Comment: I'm trying to convert my XML string from a HttpResponse to a string. Right now it's HttpResponse res = http.send(req); Then I do res.getBody() to get the XML string.

Comment: are you facing any issue while covering? please clearly tell us what do want.